# What is instance based member

Tags: c#, variables, instance-variables

in here I want to know what is instance based member? what I think is instance based member == instance variable. Am I correct? If I'm correct, then how can I know which is variable or instance variable? The variable which under constructor that will become to instance variable, right? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Variables are not members. An instance member is a field/method/property that isn't static: `private int someNumber;` Here is an exhaustive list of members https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members

Comment: Where did you read this term? Could you give a link or post a citation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An instance member is essentially anything within a class that is not marked as `static`. That is, that it can only be used after an instance of the class has been made (with the `new` keyword). This is because instance members belong to the *object*, whereas static members belong to the *class*.

Members include fields, properties, methods etc.

For example:

```
class Example
{
  public static int Value1 { get; set; } // Static property

  public int Value2 { get; set; } // Instance property

  public static string Hello() // Static method
  {
    return "Hello";
  }

  public string World() // Instance method
  {
    return " World";
  }
}

Console.WriteLine(Example.Hello() + new Example().World()); // "Hello World"
```