# C# instantiate a new class object inside same class itself as per the MS documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I came across this when I was checking the abstract classes (C# Reference) - [MS doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

Bottom of the documentation the derived class from the abstract class instantiate a new object inside the Main method.

It instantiate a new class object inside same class itself like this:

```
// Abstract class
abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected int _x = 100;
    protected int _y = 150;

    // Abstract method
    public abstract void AbstractMethod();

    // Abstract properties
    public abstract int X { get; }
    public abstract int Y { get; }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void AbstractMethod()
    {
        _x++;
        _y++;
    }

    public override int X   // overriding property
    {
        get
        {
            return _x + 10;
        }
    }

    public override int Y   // overriding property
    {
        get
        {
            return _y + 10;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var o = new DerivedClass();
        o.AbstractMethod();
        Console.WriteLine($"x = {o.X}, y = {o.Y}");
    }
}
```

I'm referring to this code snippet specifically.

`var o = new DerivedClass();`

My question is that correct?

And the other question is in the abstract class abstract methods have the following.

```
public abstract int X { get; }
public abstract int Y { get; }
```

Is that correct also?

Because in abstract methods cannot have a body.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @tkausl-Why we need to instantiate an object of a class from the same class itself? If that's ok, since it's from the Main method not an issue?

Comment: Both static methods and non static methods are completely able to create objects, including for the class they're in.

Comment: We need to create an instance of the object as Main is static, but AbstractMethod is not and requires an instance of the class to operate on. Static methods are tied to the class itself (rather than an instance of that class) and so can't access data/methods that need an object.

Comment: Regarding the abstract properties thing, the { get; } aren't really bodies, they just define how the property can be accessed (in this case you can get it but can't set it)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm referring to this code snippet specifically. `var o = new DerivedClass();` My question is that correct?

It depends on what do you mean by "correct". In terms of program compiling/working - yes, it is "correct", though a bit unconventional (maybe due to desire to make a shorter code snippet) - more often approach is to place `Main` method inside a `Program` class (or skip it completely by using [top level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements)). There are several points of interest here:

1. The `Main` method. It is the entry point of an executable program; it is where the program control starts and ends. `Main` is declared inside a `class` or `struct`. `Main` must be `static` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line)).
2. `static` modifier can be used to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static), see also - [Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members))
3. `AbstractMethod` is an instance member of class, instance members require an instance to be called (i.e. you can call static method via type name `DerivedClass.Main()` while instance one will require a created instance for example `new Derived().AbstractMethod()`)(for example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550460/what-is-instance-based-member))

> Because in abstract methods cannot have a body.

`public abstract int X { get; }` does not have a body, this is a declaration of an abstract property ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties)), though except for the `abstract` keyword it looks exactly like auto-implemented property ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)):

```cs
abstract class Abstract
{
   public abstract int X { get; }   
}

class Concrete : Abstract
{
   public Concrete(int x)
   {
       X = x; 
   }

   // readonly (can be set only in ctor) auto-implemented property
   public override int X { get; }   
}
```